# Bootstrap 4 Modal Not Showing - black screen no modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

https://jsfiddle.net/0z9mbp4r/

```
    <tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal10">Miscellaneous Title</a></td>
  <td><p>C+</p></td>
  <td><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
  <td><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
  <td><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
  <td><p>A+</p></td>
  <td><p>No</p></td>
  <td><p>B</p></td>
  <td><p>B+</p></td>
</tr>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal10" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-lg modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content p-2">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button></br></br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
            <img class="card" src="(imageinfo)" title="(info)" alt="(info)">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <h3>Name</h3>
            <p>Miscellaneous Info</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <p>Miscellaneous Info</p>
            <br>
            <a href="#">View Miscellaneous Link</a><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry the code import didn't work.

For some reason, I cannot figure out why this modal is not popping up properly? The markup is the same for each of my modals/table rows so it should be getting called properly. When I click the table row that highlights the modal, it just does the black/gray fade out and then no modal pops up? Not getting anything in the console for errors either.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to add `<table>...</table>`.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied and pasted the row from that. You can ignore that. The table works fine. The modal is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy - you made a typo.

You are missing `#` in `data-target="modal`.

Replace this:

`<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal10">Miscellaneous Title</a>`

To:

`<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal10">Miscellaneous Title</button>`

Notice that it may be better to use `<button>` to open modals.